# .Reduce without an accumulator

Tags: javascript, iterator, underscore.js, reduce

Having a lot of trouble with this, to the point where I'm desperate for a push in the correct direction.

Working on trying to complete a common Underbar (basically Underscore) exercise by writing a reduce function.  It has to satisfy four tests:

1. Should be able to sum up an array
2. Should use the first element as an accumulator when none is given
3. Should involve the iterator on the first element when given an accumulator
4. Should not invoke the iterator on the first element when using it as an accumulator

This suggests to me that there's two basic situations:

1. An accumulator is given, making accumulator != undefined, at which point you can use .each to satisfy tests 1 and 3 since you'd go through all values, starting with (accumulator, collection[0]), then (collection[0], collection[1]), and so on.  Or that's my thinking; I could be way off.

   ```
   if (accumulator != undefined) {
     _.each(collection, function(value) {
       accumulator = iterator(accumulator, value);
     });
   }
   return accumulator;
   ```
2. Tests 2 and 4 still fail because no accumulator is given, and at that point, I'm lost.  I don't think .each can be used.  Basically I have to tell this to start with collection[0] and iterate through the rest, but I'm completely lost.  I'm still very new to coding and a lot of this has yet to fully sink in.

Any help that can be provided is deeply appreciated.  If my thinking is wrong on how these functions work, please feel free to correct that as well.  I'm just looking for help.

Comment: What about a normal `for` loop?

Comment: Have look at using _.first and _.rest when an accumulator is not supplied

Answer (score 0):

The following code should due the job.

```js
Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, accumulator){
 var needsAccum = arguments.length <2;
 if (this.length === 0){
  return this;
 }
 this.forEach(function(item){
  if (needsAccum){
   accumulator = item;
   needsAccum = false;
  }
  else{
   accumulator = callback(accumulator, item)
  }
 })
 return accumulator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize part of the question:

"How can I use to _.each to iterate, when sometimes I will have to skip the first iteration" - "won't _.each iterate through at every index?"

For me, I found the solution was to put an if/else statement in my _.each

```
_.each(collection, function(value, index) {
  if (accumulator === undefined){
    accumulator = item;
  } else {
    accumulator = iterator(accumulator, value);
  }
}
```

Basically, putting your if statement inside of the _.each rather than before it. 
In the first iteration, if there is no accumulator, the loop will go into the "IF", and will skip the "ELSE"